# EXC_BAD_ACCESS with convenience init() after upgrading to Xcode7

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, swift2

(Note: The issue is not present when a storyboard is used, it is reproduced only without a storyboard i.e. programatically)

After upgrading to Xcode7, code which was working earlier is now throwing an EXC_BAD_ACCESS. I reproduced the issue with the simple code below:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

convenience init() {
    self.init()
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
}

override init(nibName nibNameOrNil: String?, bundle nibBundleOrNil: NSBundle?) {
    super.init(nibName: nibNameOrNil, bundle: nibBundleOrNil)
}
}
```

The convenience init is doing an endless call to itself till the point the exception is thrown, if this is the expected behaviour then why does it work with the storyboard and why was it working earlier prior to Xcode7.
The backtrace is below:

thread #1: tid = 0x11ec92, 0x00025dd4 InitTest`InitTest.ViewController.init (self=0x00000000)() -> InitTest.ViewController at ViewController.swift:18, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x38ffc)
frame #0: 0x00025dd4 InitTest`InitTest.ViewController.init (self=0x00000000)() -> InitTest.ViewController at ViewController.swift:18
frame #1: 0x00025df8 InitTest`InitTest.ViewController.init (self=0x00000000)() -> InitTest.ViewController + 36 at ViewController.swift:19
frame #2: 0x00025df8 InitTest`InitTest.ViewController.init (self=0x00000000)() -> InitTest.ViewController + 36 at ViewController.swift:19
frame #3: 0x00025df8 InitTest`InitTest.ViewController.init (self=0x00000000)() -> InitTest.ViewController + 36 at ViewController.swift:19
frame #4: 0x00025df8 InitTest`InitTest.ViewController.init (self=0x00000000)() -> InitTest.ViewController + 36 at ViewController.swift:19
frame #5: 0x00025df8 InitTest`InitTest.ViewController.init (self=0x00000000)() -> InitTest.ViewController + 36 at ViewController.swift:19

Comment: It works when using a storyboard because the storyboard doesn't call `init()`.  I don't know why it worked before Xcode7, I find it pretty surprising that that would ever work.

Comment: Yes, it shouldn't have worked in the first place.

Comment: dan can you please put your comment as the answer and I will accept it.